# Proof that there are infinitely many primes of the form $6k+1$. Proof verification

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-verification

> **Theorem.** there are infinitely many primes of the form $6k+1$.

I've just proved that there are infinitely many primes of the form $6k+1$.

**Could you please check my proof?**

At first, I proved that

> $$ for \ \  p:prime, \ p \ge 5 \\\ \\ \left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)= \begin{cases} 1,&
>  \ p \equiv 1 \pmod  6 \\ 
> -1, &  \ p \equiv 5 \pmod  6 \end{cases} $$
>   (I will use this lemma for proving Theorem.)

$$$$
NOW assume that there are finite primes of the form $6k+1$.

then we can say $ \ p_1, \ p_2, \cdots, p_k
\ $ :  all the  primes  of the form  $6k+1$.

**Let**

> $$ n=(p_1\cdot p_2\cdots\ p_k)^2  +3, $$

then (by Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic) there is prime factor $p$ of $n$.

$$
$$
Id est, $$(p_1\cdot p_2\cdots\ p_k)^2  \equiv -3  \pmod  p  $$

So, $$p \equiv 1 \pmod  6$$

Thus $$p=p_i \ for \ some \ i=1, \cdots , k$$

This time

$$p=p_i \  \ \ divides  \ \   (p_1\cdot p_2\cdots\ p_k)^2
\\
p=p_i \  \ \ can't \ \ divide  \ \   3
\\
$$

So, $$p=p_i  \ \ can't \ \  divide  \ \ n. \\$$

It is contradiction with "$p$ is prime factor of $n$"

$\therefore \ $ There are infinitely many primes of the form $6k+1$.

$Q.E.D.$

$$
$$
What about my proof?

After proving, I saw someone's proof,

BUT he **set** $$ n=(2p_1\cdot p_2\cdots\ p_k)^2  +3 $$

**I don't know why he set** $ n=(2p_1\cdot p_2\cdots\ p_k)^2  +3 $, **instead of** $ n=(p_1\cdot p_2\cdots\ p_k)^2  +3 $.

*Is my proof wrong?*

$$
$$
Please give me some hand.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your $n$ is congruent to $4$ mod $6$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Ah.. You mean if $n \equiv 4 \pmod  6$, then 2 is prime factor of n... Thus this is wrong, right??

Comment: I wouldn't say wrong, but incomplete. Note that you can also solve the issue by noting that $x^2\equiv1\pmod8$ for odd $x$, which means your $n$ cannot be a power of $2$, hence has an odd prime divisor.

Comment: @barto, Ummm $x^2\equiv1\pmod8$ iff $x \equiv1, 3, 5, 7\pmod8$ iff $x \equiv1 \pmod2$.. How does it go "It means your n cannot be a power of 2" Could you explain more , please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a minor issue. Not every prime divisor of your $n$ is necessarily of the form $6k+1$. (Because, as you noted, the theorem with the Légendre-symbol is only valid for $p\geqslant5$.)  You would have to argue that $2$ and $3$ do not divide $n$.
This can be fixed by letting $n=(2p_1,\cdots,p_k)^2+3$ as you noted, or alternatively by observing that $x^2\equiv1\pmod8$ for odd $x$, which means your $n$ cannot be a power of $2$, hence has an odd prime divisor.

Comment: THANKS a lot for answering. I agree "argue that 2 do not divide n", BUT why I argue that '3 do not divide n'?  $n=(p_1\cdot p_2\cdots\ p_k)^2  +3$ is the form 6k+1+3=6k+4 .. isn't it? Do I get wrong thing? Give me some advice, please:-)

Comment: It is indeed obvious that $3$ does not divide $n$, but it's worth noting because it's still a crucial step in your proof.

Comment: THANK you sincerely. :-) AND Just to be sure...I'm sorry if it offended you.

Comment: Not at all ;-), you're welcome.

Comment: By the way... $x^2\equiv1\pmod8$ iff $x\equiv1,3,5,7\pmod8$ iff $x\equiv1\pmod2$.. How does it go "It means your n cannot be a power of 2" Could you explain more , please?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again.. Just to be sure I thought... If I suppose that my $n$ cannot be a power of 2.  Because my $n$ is larger than 3, so $n$ has a prime factor $p$ ($\neq 2$). Also 3 does not divide $n$. Hence $n$ has prime factor $p$ of the form 6k+1 (by Lemma). Is this right?

Comment: If $n=(p_1\cdot p_2\cdots\ p_k)^2  +3$ is power of 2, then (can say) $n=2^m$ for some $m \in N$.

Because $(p_1\cdot p_2\cdots\ p_k)^2$ is odd, so $(p_1\cdot p_2\cdots\ p_k)^2\equiv1\pmod{2^m}$.

That is $n=(p_1\cdot p_2\cdots\ p_k)^2  +3\equiv1+3\equiv4\pmod{2^m}$.

BUT $n=2^m \ge 7^2+3=51$. Hence, $n\equiv4\not\equiv0\pmod{2^m}$. i.e. $n\not\equiv0\pmod n$.  CONTRADICTION.

Comment: NOW I understand what you teaching me. :-) I've learned a lot.  THANKS for your answer again!

Comment: Well done! Apologies for not answering your questions immediately, I wasn't at home last evening.

Comment: @user143993 Sorry to bother you, but how did you manage to get $(p_1\cdot p_2\dots p_k)^2\equiv 1\pmod{2^m}$?

Comment: It's not true, and you don't need it. You only need that it is $\equiv 1 \pmod 8$.

Answer (score 3):

If we cross out from sequence of positive integers all numbers divisible by $2$ and all numbers divisible by $3$, then all remaining numbers will be in one of two forms:

$S1(n)=6n−1=5,11,17,...$ or $S2(n)=6n+1=7,13,19,....n=1,2,3,...$ So all prime numbers also will be in one of these two forms and ratio 0f number of primes in the sequence $S1(n)$ to number of primes in the sequence $S2(n)$ tends to be $1$. see [link]

Comment: see [link] (_http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=13752&lngWId=3_)

Comment: see [link](_https://www.academia.edu/13890086/Matrix_sieve_the_easiest_way_to_find_prime_numbers_)