# Question about Twin Primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let:

```
P = (11, 17, 29, 41, 59, 71, 101, ...} and Q = {13, 19, 31, 43, 61, 73, 103, ...}.
```

It is well known that both P and Q are infinite sets (please, view the following two references):

[Math Forum](https://mathhelpforum.com/threads/infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-6k-5-and-6k-1.109462/)

[Math Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825917/proof-that-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-6k1-proof-verificati)

The map defined by:

```
  f : P -> Q , f(K) = (K + 2);

  f^(-1) : Q -> P , f^(-1)(K) = (K - 2);
```

defines a bijection between P and Q.

My question is :
Why can' t  we  conclude (by the above facts ) that the set:

```
 Twin Primes = {(11, 13), (17, 19), (29, 31), (41, 43), (59, 61), (71, 73), (101, 103) ...}
```

is an infinite set?

Thank you!

Comment: We only know that each set has infinitely many primes but we don’t necessarily know their frequency (in some sense, the primes have to occur at the same frequency to be a twin prime).

Comment: Please use MathJax. [Here’s a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: No idea why you think we know that $P,Q$ are infinite, or even how you have defined $P,Q,$ since you left out $5$ and $7.$

Comment: If $P,Q$ are the sets of primes of the form $6k-1$ and $6k+1,$ respectively, we know they are both infinite, but $37$ is in $Q$ and $35$ is not in $Q.$

Comment: As the answer below points out , you used that there are infinite many twin primes to prove that there are infinite many twin primes.

Answer (score 3):

> It is well known that both P and Q are infinite sets

If you are defining the sets P and Q so that for any positive integer $n$, the $n$-th element in P and the $n$-th element in Q form a pair of twin primes, then the above statement represents circular reasoning, where you are assuming that there are an infinite number of pairs of twin primes.

If you are not so defining the sets P and Q, then you can **not** use the bijection argument to establish that there are an infinite number of pairs of twin primes.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback about my question.